# how to pass no quote character as a value to ADF parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass no quote character as a value to my ADF parameters.
We are calling this parameter value in copy activity in one of the datasets.

Note: There is an option to Select a Single quote, Double quote, and No quote character from the dropdown, Instead of selecting I want to pass from parameters.

My sample looks like 
File with no quotes 
A,B,name 
1,2,abc 
2,3,cde 
4,5,xyz 
4,2,pqrs

File with partial double quotes where ever it requires
A,B,name 
1,2,"abc,,|,cde" 
2,3,"xyz,abc" 
4,5,pqr 
4,2,cvd

File with double quotes for all columns
A,B,name 
"1","2","abc,,|,cde" 
"1","2","xyz,,|,abc" 
"1","2","cvd,,|,bbb"

Expected output-
If a file has no quotes, we should get no quotes in the output

Note: Above three scenarios can be handle in a single copy activity (ADF pipelines)

Comment: That's a tough one, but can you clarify, do you want the quotes to be in the final file or not?

Comment: We want final files in double quotes